# How to share a single static class code among different applications

Tags: c#, singleton, distributed-system

In simple words, I want to write a class for Encryption/Decryption which will be used by different web applications on the same server. Besides, all the methods of this class are also static.

I put the created dll in the GAC. However, it seems that every application creates its own encryption object in memory.

Is there any way to have just one instance of this class for the sake of performance and memory usage?

Thanks

Comment: Srsly.. how big of a footprint are your encryption routines leaving?  Have you confirmed that is an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually validated that this is a concern? That would be quite surprising.

But no, strictly speaking, you can't share an instance (or static class) across applications--you can't even share one across `AppDomain`s in the same application (you end up using a proxy object). To accomplish what you want, you'll have to use some kind of client-server architecture, which will almost certainly introduce more overhead than the encryption system itself.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you cannot create a singleton across processes.

**Instead** you can create your own process (e.g. a Windows service, or daemon in *NIX worlds) that others then use. For inter-process communication ([RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)) there are variety of methods such as: named pipes, sockets (and higher application protocols that use them), reading and writing to file...

**However**, may I ask why you think a class per process will consume so much memory? As for performance the fact that there are more processes, assuming they sit idle until called, there shouldn't be difference in having many - indeed it should be faster otherwise you will have to take concurrency into account.